# NodeJS server no http for Redis subscription

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I want to develop a process that only subscribes to a Redis channel and stay alive to handle received messages.

I wrote the following code:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var sub = redis.createClient({host: process.env.REDIS_HOST});

console.log('subscribing...')
sub.on('subscribe', () => console.log('subscribed'));
sub.on('message', (ch, msg) => console.log(`Received message on ${ch}:${msg}`));
console.log('done')
```

But obviously it does not work: when launched it goes through all lines and dies. I think I don't need framework like Express because my process does not use http.

How could I write a server that stay alive "forever" without using http frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not subscribing to a channel:

```
sub.subscribe('channel');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the exact code above and the process stays open.  In the code above you aren't publishing any messages, therefore you will only see "subscribing..." and "done" printed to the terminal.

Also, as mentioned you aren't subscribing to the channel either.